# Angular-cli: ng serve without optimisations

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using the angular-cli and really like the features it comes with. I've just noticed that when `ng serve -dev` is run from the terminal, it outputs the following information about optimisation:

```
6ms module order optimization
7ms module id optimization
13ms chunk reviving
10ms chunk order optimization
46ms chunk id optimization
```

Is it possible to turn off these optimizations? My thoughts are that it could speed up the builds when running the development server.

Comment: that is 82ms, the bootstrap of the app in the browser takes seconds, I suspect that the optimization is there the minimize bootsrap-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular CLI does not support disabling asset optimization at time of writing this answer.

I have raised it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1980#issuecomment-268855680), which is an issue for all Angular CLI build speed issues, as when someone created a specific issue for it, they set it as a duplicate of this issue.

So, you can watch that issue, +1 my comment, or add your own to help bring more focus to it.